# align struct having vector as a member (c++)

Tags: c++, vector, sizeof

```
struct bar {
  int32 a;    // 4 bytes
  int32 b;    // 4 bytes
  vector<int> c;      // something like 8 or 16 bytes?
}
```

When I do sizeof(bar) it gives 32 bytes!
Any way I could **align** it to be something smaller? Any potential
penalty for that? I am not quite sure about the vector part...

Comment: Why do you care?  When you try to go messing with alignment, you have to use non-standard compiler-specific extensions. Since you're certainly not sending this out as a packet or writing it to a binary file, just don't worry about it.

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit architecture? That's already optimal. A vector takes three words.

Comment: I would expect the vector to contain two pointers and one `size_t`, or possibly three pointers. On a 64-bit system, that would be 24 bytes.

Comment: When I do sizeof(vector<int>), it gives 16

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232198/about-vectors-growth

Comment: @VaibhavDesai The link is irrelevant to this question.

OP: What are you trying to do exactly? Doesn't seem right to me to be worrying about the size of a struct for no valid reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal implementation of `std::vector<T, A>` is to have a pointer to have three pointers plus, for stateful allocators, whatever it takes to maintain the allocator:

1. A pointer to the start of the vector.
2. A pointer to the end of the vector or the number of elements in the vector.
3. A pointer to the end of the allocated memory or the number of elements allocated.

When putting this into a type, it will likely be padded to 4 words to improve access times. When you combine a vector like this with two more data members, you'll naturally get a type which occupies 8 words, three of which are to align the type for fast access.

If you really care about the size of your `struct`s containing vector because the vector is normally empty and only rarely contains data, you'd probably prefer an implementation with a different layout: The vector would still need to start the information mentioned above but it could start the data with the allocated buffer: When allocating memory, the vector would allocate extra space to prepend its administration information to the actual values and store a pointer to the allocated data (probably to the first element which, however, makes recovery of the administration information not portable).

Using a representation just described, the size of the vector would be one word and the total size of your `struct` would be three words plus padding, i.e., probably 4 words. The better size is traded for a small overhead when the size or the capacity of the vector is needed (e.g., when using `begin()` and `end()).

In general, the size of the vectors tends not to matter because the actual memory consumption of the vectors is down to the elements in the vector.