# Convert string to array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

So I have a string called c. I am reading it in from a file using this:

```
fscanf(file, "%[^/0]", &c);
```

I have another variable declared as char* array[41]. I need this to be an array of the individual words/strings of c.

The issue is that I do not know how many individual words/strings will be in c, since I'm getting it as a whole line from a file. My idea was to put it into the array character by character and if it is white space i can replace it with null character, but I'm 95% sure that doesn't work at all. My other idea was if I could somehow know how many strings are in the line and capture each as a string to put in the array, but then I'm afraid it will mess with what comes after that line since I cannot be sure how many strings there are.

Comment: don't talk abstract. write code. **show** your code. ask about **specific** problems.

Comment: You can use `strtok()`. It is sufficient to handle it. But access is not as you described.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what [`strtok(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) does. All you need to do is allocate an "array", for example

```
size_t num = 16;
char **arr = malloc(num * sizeof(char *));
```

then fill it with the results of `strtok()` and count ... if you reach `num`, do something like

```
if (count == num)
{
    num *= 2;
    arr = realloc(arr, num * sizeof(char *));
}
```

add error checking for `malloc()` and `realloc()`.

Comment: Where does the 16 come from? Why have exponential growth?

Comment: @EdHeal make it 1, will work, too. It's an assumption, nothing else.

Comment: @EdHeal and regarding your edit, that's a common idiom reducing the `realloc()` calls for large inputs dramatically.

Comment: What about the exponential growth?

Comment: @EdHeal in general, allocate an amount suitable for >50% of the expected inputs, then double if it turns out to be to little. It's just a common strategy.

Comment: Where is this known as a common strategy?

Comment: The array is a defined size, so how does this work if im using char* arr[40]?

Comment: @EdHeal e.g. in many containers of higher level languages, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232198/about-vectors-growth

Comment: I need it to be of type char* array[40], so how do I avoid the char**?

Comment: @Taylor "since I cannot be sure how many strings there are." <- that's what you wrote. `strtok()` will just replace delimeters specified by you with `0` bytes and return the pointers to the now split string. You have to store them somewhere.

Comment: @Taylor why do you *need* the elements to have exactly 40 bytes? You shouldn't care about their length.

Comment: @FelixPalmen - Is not 1.5 the more common value? (i.e. the golden ratio).

Comment: @EdHeal it might be the "more optimal" value, but more common is 2, probably for the sake of simplicity. (and btw, the golden ratio would be 1.62)

Comment: 1. How is it more simple? 2. Evidence for you assumption that 2 is more common?

Comment: @EdHeal get on someone else's nerves.

Comment: @EdHeal haha, how mature, downvoting as a revenge for showing your cluelessness. well, thanks :p

Comment: array[40] was defined as a part of my assignment. I have it compiling with the version you did except arr* instead of arr** (it said this is incompatible pointer type) but then I still need to transfer that to my original array

Comment: @Taylor, are you sure you weren't given a maximum number of words to split, too? otherwise, this just complicates it ....

Comment: @FelixPalmen - I just do not think it is a good answer

Comment: the max characters are 80 that will be in the line. part of the array can and most of the time will be empty

Comment: @Taylor I'm talking about a maximum size of the array. In that case, just declare it as a variable (no need for dynamic allocation) and fill it using `strncpy()` (on the return values of `strtok()`).

Comment: @EdHeal and I don't care, because it's the straight forward answer to the initial state of the question. The allocation strategy is a suggestion which is pretty clear from the text. And, if you like it or not, it *is* a very common strategy.

Comment: @EdHeal as if there weren't enough comments already, but just to give you a little insight in case you're interested: `2` is the closest approximation of the *golden ratio* in integers. Turns out OP doesn't need dynamic allocation at all, but it still might be valuable for future readers. And to address your first edited comment: It's *always* exponential, no matter what the actual factor is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the length of the string,reallocate the size of some dynamically allocated array accordingly.than you can store individual words in another array.check this out :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int GetWords(const char *String,char buffer[][255]);

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[30][255];

    const char *sentence = "Hello how are you";

    int num_of_words = GetWords(sentence,buffer);

    for( int n = 0 ; n < num_of_words ; n++ )
    {
        printf("word %d : %s\n" , n+1 , buffer[n]);
        //or do something else
    }

    return 0;
}

int GetWords(const char *String,char buffer[][255])
{
    int x = -1 , y = 0 , z = 0 ;

     size_t len = strlen(String) , n = 0 ;

    for( n = 0 ; n < len ; n++ )
    {
        y++;

        if( String[n] == ' ' /* || String[n] == ',' */ )
        {
            y = 0;
            z = 0;
        }

        if( y == 1 ) x++;

        if( y > 0 )
        {
            buffer[x][z] = String[n];
            z++;
            buffer[x][z] = '\0';
        }
    }

    //return number of words
    return (x+1);
}
```