# Why Vector's size() and capacity() is different after push_back()

Tags: c++, vector, allocation

I just starting to learning vectors and little confused about `size()` and `capacity()`
I know little about both of them. But why in this program both are different? even `array(10)` is making room for 10 elements and initializing with 0.

**Before adding `array.push_back(5)`**

So `array.size();` is 10 that is ok.

So `array.capacity();` is 10 that is ok.

**After adding `array.push_back(5)`**

So `array.size();` is 11 that is ok `(already 10 time 0 is added and then push_back add one more element 5 )`.

So `array.capacity();` is 15 Why? `( is it reserving 5 blocks for one int? )`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    std::vector<int> array(10); // make room for 10 elements and initialize with 0
    array.reserve(10);    // make room for 10 elements
    array.push_back(5);
    std::cout << array.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << array.capacity() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you shouldn't use `array` as a variable name; especially when the type isn't an array. I realize this is just example code, but still probably just a good idea. :)

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Comment: @PeteBecker true, but in this case, where the output is diagnostic, we tend to want the implicit `flush` that `endl` has, otherwise messages won't necessarily appear until later and/or in the wrong order. (at least this has been my experience)

Comment: @underscore_d - maybe, but that doesn't apply to the code here.

Comment: @PeteBecker I really like extra comments like yours one. Thanks it clear my confusion more about `std::endl` and `\n` :) and force me to learn more about buffer and why it's important can you help me or link me related to buffer in c++?

Comment: @erip thanks to point out. Just to confirm because array is a built-in STL?

Comment: Yes, and it's misrepresentatitive because it's *not an array*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Standard mandates that `std::vector<T>::push_back()` has amortized `O(1)` complexity. This means that the expansion has to be geometrically, say doubling the amount of storage each time it has been filled.

Simple example: sequentially `push_back` 32 `int`s into a `std::vector<int>`. You will store all of them once, and also do 31 copies if you double the capacity each time it runs out. Why 31? Before storing the 2nd element, you copy the 1st; before storing the 3rd, you copy elements 1-2, before storing the 5th, you copy 1-4, etc. So you copy 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 31 times, with 32 stores.

Doing the formal analysis shows that you get `O(N)` stores and copies for `N` elements. This means amortized `O(1)` complexity *per `push_back`* (often only a store without a copy, sometimes a store and a sequence of copies).

Because of this expansion strategy, you will have `size() < capacity()` most of the time. Lookup `shrink_to_fit` and `reserve` to learn how to control a vector's capacity in a more fine-grained manner.

**Note**: with geometrical growth rate, any factor larger than 1 will do, and there have been some studies claiming that 1.5 gives better performance because of less wasted memory (because at some point the reallocated memory can overwrite the old memory).

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that expanding the space by a factor of 1.5 (which is what the OPs library appears to be doing) still gives amortized constant time capacity, but (can) do more copies - but have less wasted memory.

Comment: @MartinBonner thanks, updated. Though that claim has never really been substantiated AFAIK.

Comment: Which claim?  Still amortized constant? or reduced memory usage?  (They both seem obvious to me.)

Comment: @MartinBonner reduced memory OK, but better *performance* because of that, has not been substantiated.

Comment: Hmm.  I thought it was an approach to prevent out-of-memory errors, rather than improve performance per-se.

Comment: @MartinBonner see this [long Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2ezy59/facebooks_stdvector_optimization/) for further info (it has popped recently as well, but can't find it)

Answer (score 10):

It is for efficiency so that it does not have to expand the underlying data structure each time you add an element. i.e. not having to call `delete`/`new` each time.

Comment: Also for avoiding copying all elements on expansion many times, I guess.

Comment: So we can't tell the exact capacity() of any vector?

Comment: @UnKnown yes, we can: `capacity()` returns the number of elements that can be contained before a new reallocation.

Answer (score 7):

The [std::vector::capacity](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/) is not its actual size (which is returned by `size()`), but the size of the actual internal allocated size.

In other terms, it is the size that it can reach before another re-allocation is needed.

It doesn't increase by 1 each time you do a `push_back` in order to not call a new reallocation (which is a heavy call) on each inserted element. It reserves more, because it doesn't know if you won't do some other `push_back` just after, and in this case, it won't have to change allocated memory size for the 4 next elements.

Here, 4 next elements is a compromise between 1, that would optimize memory allocation at maximum but would risk another reallocation soon, and a huge number, that would allow you to make many `push_back` quickly but maybe reserve a lot of memory for nothing.

**Note**: if you want to specify a capacity yourself (if you know your vector maximum size for instance), you can do it with [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) member function.

Comment: I already used reserve(); but I'm confused why capacity jumped to 15 even I just added/push_back just one integer?

Comment: @UnKnown: You didn't reserve space for 11 elements, though.

Comment: @UnKnown Because it allocate more than one element in order to not reallocate for the few next ones and limit realloc number. The more it resize, the more it resize large in order to restrain `reserve` intern calls.

Comment: So in this case we can't tell the exact capacity() of vector?

Comment: @UnKnown If you know how the memory management of your vector works (that can depend of the system, compiler etc), you can predict it. But it is almost always a compromise between allocated memory size and reallocations number. (Which represent respectively used RAM and used CPU)

Comment: @Unknown: You can't reliable *predict* what capacity will be if you just do `push_back` - but you can tell afterwards, and if you really care, you can set it with `reserve`.

Comment: If capacity was increased by 1 only, then every single push_back () would have to increase the capacity, which is an operation that is somewhere between "expensive" and "very expensive". By changing the capacity to 15, the next four calls to push_back () are much cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
std::vector<int> array(10); // make room for 10 elements and initialize with 0
```

You actually filled all the ten spaces with zeros. Adding ad additional element will cause the capacity to be expanded thanks for efficiency.
In your case it is useless to call the function reserve because you have instantiated the same number of elements.

check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) and [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/) link

Answer (score 2):

I think the following question can give you more detail about the capacity of a vector.

[About Vectors growth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232198/about-vectors-growth)

I will reference the answer in above question.

The growth strategy of `capacity` is required to meet the amortized constant time requirement for the `push_back` operation. Then, the strategy is designed to have a exponential growth generally when the space is lack. In short, the `size` of vector indicate the number of elements now, while the `captacity` show its ability used to `push_back` in future.

Answer (score 1):

`Size()` returns how many values you have in the vector.

And `capacity()` returns size of allocated storage capacity means how many values it can hold now.

Comment: why capacity changed after calling push_back()?

Comment: To accomodate the upcoming elements in that vector.

Comment: So we can't tell the exact capacity()?

Comment: @UnKnown `capacity()` *is* the exact capacity. It grows when necessary, but in larger "steps" than the size. You can't tell what the capacity will be in the future, but you can always tell what it is right now.

Comment: Because the data structure allocates memory in runtime.