# Remaining memory before relocating vector c++

Tags: c++

Suppose I am using a vector of int a:

```
vector<int> a {1, 2, 34, 1222, 0};
```

Then, I want to push_back some datas like this:

```
a.push_back (data);
```

However, my program have to add a lot of data on my vector.

I am learning c++ on a book. The book says: "Adding an element can sometimes require additional storage be allocated. In that case, every element must be moved into the new storage", the c++ Ressources Network adding that "This is a relatively expensive task in terms of processing time.". I also find an [article](https://www.quora.com/How-is-memory-allocated-to-std-vector-when-we-push_back-elements-into-it) about the subject.

However, my program have to be very fast. So, I can not deal with this "relocation" of my vector. In fact the size of my vector can be up than 1GO of memory.

---

My question is quite simple:

How can I know the remaining memory before relocating my huge vector?

---

**Note:** I do not know the finally size of my vector so I can not initialize it keeping the necessary memory.

*Tell me if you have some questions or some comments.*

Comment: *[std::vector::capacity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) returns the number of elements that the container has currently allocated space for.* When you insert an element and `std::vector::capacity` equals to `std::vector::size` then reallocation happens.

Comment: The remaining memory of your system or the remaining/reserved memory in the vector?

Comment: You should not really worry about vector internals. It works quite good. Different containers have different complexities for different task. Choose the one that best fits your use case.

Comment: You *could* use `a.capacity` but I'm not sure what you are planning on doing with that information.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What problem are you _actually_ trying to resolve?

Comment: if that article didnt mention capacity of the vector or `vector::reserve` then it missed the point

Comment: @ChrisDrew OP could manually reserve additional memory to improve the performance for a specific use case.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5232342/612920

Comment: Look like you should consider using `std::deque`.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I'm all for using `vector::reserve` if possible but I don't see how using `vector::capacity` helps in OPs case.

Comment: "my program have to be very fast. So, I can not deal with this relocation". We call this **premature optimization**. Having said that, it would be a wise advice to stick to the _generic_ container interface (defined by `begin()/end()` iterators)  so you can swap to other containers if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` has methods for this case:

[capacity()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) returns current number of elements, for which memory is allocated. So if the number of elements in vector would exceed this number, reallocation will happen

[reserve()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) allocates memory for given number of elements. If given number is less than `capacity()`, it does nothing. Otherwise, it reallocates to provide the required capacity.

Answer (score 2):

If you knew how big your `vector` would be eventually then you could use [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to avoid any reallocations but you say that is not possible.

[`vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) is guaranteed to be amortized constant. It achieves this by allocating more memory than it needs. As the `vector` gets larger there will be fewer and fewer reallocations. `vector` is designed for this so I suggest you try it and then measure performance to see if the reallocations are a problem.

Comment: If, having measured, the performance is still problematic, switching to `std::deque` will be very little change, and is safe as long as you don't need a `ContiguousContainer`

Comment: @Caleth Sure. There is no guarantee `std::deque` will improve performance though. `std::vector` will have better data locality. Allocations will be faster with `std::deque` but it will have to do more allocations in total if the container size is large.