# How memory works if vectors inside class array are dynamically push_backed?

Tags: c++, class, vector, memory-reallocation

Assume that we have following class:

```
class Test {
public:
   Test() {}
   std::vector<int>& getIntList() {
      return intList;
   }
private:
   std::vector<int> intList;
};
```

Also, we have following codes inside main function to declare class array:

```
int main(void) {
   Test* test[20];

   for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
      test[i] = new Test();
   }
}
```

In these cases, test objects are instantiated.

Now if I append multiple items in the vector inside each class randomly,

there might exist chances to collide memory address range of each vector inside each class while resizing their memory size.

In this case, is the entire 'test' object copied into other memory area and vector is resized?
Or, is vector STL only copied into other memory area and resized while the class references the vector?

Entirely, is not a good idea to code like this?

Comment: Entirely, is not a good idea to code like this? No it is not, forget about using `new` outside of constructing smartpointers until you really need it (probably never)

Comment: @formerlyknownas What i questioned was that is it good idea to manage vector(memory) like this

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, why do you think that anything might "collide" here?

Comment: You could write a much less contrived version with two `std::vector<int>` objects in local scope.

Comment: i dont really understand. You are not managing the vectors memory, the vector does that for you

Comment: Anyway, the answer is that the vector object doesn't grow when you add elements to it - the top-level object manages some dynamically-allocated storage _elsewhere_. Your false premise is that increasing `vector.size()` affects `sizeof(vector)`, and it doesn't.

Comment: vectors do not store their elements on the stack if thats your source of confusion

Comment: "there might exist chances to collide memory address range of each vector inside each class while resizing their memory size." This part is not at all clear

Comment: Classes have a fixed compile-time size in C++. Nothing grows or shrinks on the stack. How do you think `sizeof` works without evaluating its parameters?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://Xyproblem.info), what are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jabberwocky since vector will be resized while pushing back, vectors inside each class can't resize its area consecutively, which means they have to be copied into other memory area and has to be resized in that area.

Comment: Yes the vectors will be resized, so where is the problem?

Comment: *vectors inside each class can't resize its area consecutively,* -- What does one vector have to do with the other?  They are separate objects -- one knows nothing or cares about what the other is doing.

Comment: Vector does not *"grow inside each class"* That is not a thing. Vector does not store its data on the stack

Comment: sry I think I have to edit my question.

Comment: related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478523/how-does-stdvector-support-contiguous-memory-for-custom-objects-of-unknown-siz

Comment: anyway now i understand something that i have missed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
struct foo {
    std::vector<int> x;
    std::vector<int> y;
};
```

Now `sizeof(foo)` is a compile time constant. It does not change when you add elements to the vectors. Also `sizeof(std::vector<int>)` is constant.

The size of a `foo` instance is not increasing when the `size()` of the vector grows. It is similar to having a dynamic array (only for the sake of the example):

```
struct bar {
   int* c_array;
};
```

Here, `sizeof(bar)` is likely to be just `sizeof(int*)`, because it is just a pointer, even though it could point to the first element of a c-style array, or to a single `int`.

Comment: This is what I want to know. Thank you. So does the vector act as dynamic array initialized with small size(by programmer)?

Comment: @sungjuncho Yes, `std::vector` is a dynamic array that keeps its elements on the heap. `std::array` is a static array allocated at compile time, that cannot change its size. And don't bother with C-style arrays in new code.

Comment: @sungjuncho hm yes, kind of. `std::vector` is much more than that. Just to name one example, it has an `operator==` that does what you want, something that is unnecessarily complicated with c-arrays