# How does std::vector::reserve() know how much memory each element requires?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I understand how std::vector::reserve() works with vectors of primitive types:

```
vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(100);
```

Say you created an empty vector of objects:

```
class A {
    public:
    string name;
}

vector<A> vec;
vec.reserve(100);
```

How does it know how much memory to reserve? Not only that, but what if class A had a container inside of it as well? Then it would be impossible to reserve the correct amount of memory right?

Comment: `sizeof(A)` is a fixed value which doesn't depend on the length of the string contained by `name`

Comment: `std::string` also has a fixed size, it just has pointers to dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: *but what if class A had a container inside of it as well? Then it would be impossible to reserve the correct amount of memory right?* See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478523/how-does-stdvector-support-contiguous-memory-for-custom-objects-of-unknown-siz/55478808#55478808) for why that is not an issue

Comment: The other scenario that is usually mentioned in questions like these is "What about `std::vector<Base>`, how can it know how big the derived classes are?  The answer being "Polymorphism necessitates using *pointers* or *references*, otherwise you will get object slicing."

Comment: Hint:  using `sizeof` and the template parameter will give you the size, in bytes, of one element.  For example, with `std::vector<int>`, the `sizeof(int)` will return the size of one element.

Answer (score 2):

The container knows the size of the element type by virtue of knowing the definition of that type. There is an operator in C++ that returns the size of a complete (i.e. defined) type. `sizeof(T)` returns the size of the type `T`.

> what if class A had a container inside of it as well? Then it would be impossible to reserve the correct amount of memory right?

That wouldn't be a problem at all. The size of all types is constant in C++.