# Size of an object of a class containing a string and an integer data member

Tags: c++, string, sizeof

I found this code on geeksforgeeks while studying about new operator overloading:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
 
using namespace std;
class student
{
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    student()
    {
        cout<< "Constructor is called\n" ;
    }
    student(string name, int age)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<< "Name:" << name << endl;
        cout<< "Age:" << age << endl;
    }
    void * operator new(size_t size)
    {
        cout<< "Overloading new operator with size: " << size << endl;
        void * p = ::operator new(size);
        //void * p = malloc(size); will also work fine
     
        return p;
    }
 
    void operator delete(void * p)
    {
        cout<< "Overloading delete operator " << endl;
        free(p);
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    student * p = new student("Yash", 24);
 
    p->display();
    delete p;
}
```

In the output it is showing that the number of bytes of memory to be allocated for the object is `40 bytes`. The size of string datatype is `32 bytes` and the integer is `4 bytes` then shouldn't it be `36 bytes` ?

Comment: What value are you expecting?  Also, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478523/how-does-stdvector-support-contiguous-memory-for-custom-objects-of-unknown-siz

Comment: An obvious answer would be "the size of `string` plus the size of `int`". But this is too obvious, probably not answering your question! If so, please explain what you really want to ask. You can [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Why should 36 plus 4 be 36, and not 40?

Comment: @NathanOliver the sizeof(string) was coming out to be 32 bytes not 36...

Comment: Woops.  Missed that.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58435348/what-is-bit-padding-or-padding-bits-exactly/58436082#58436082

Comment: I get 40 for a 64-bit build and 28 for a 32-bit build. The size of a `std::string` is 32 and 24, respectively. So there's 4 bytes of padding before the `string` member in the 64-bit build ... to 8-byte align a pointer member thereof, I expect.

Comment: @NathanOliver Why would there be padding shouldn't the memory allocation be just 32 bytes for the string and 4 bytes for the int as 4 is also a multiple of 32?

Comment: But 36 is not a multiple of `8` (64 bits) which appears to be what you are using.

Comment: Try inverting the order of the `int` and `string` members ... that may give you your missing 4 bytes back (or it may not).

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay I think I got it, thanks!

Comment: If you compile this in `gcc` and use the `-Wpadded` switch the compiler will warn you that it's adding `4` bytes of padding for this particular case.

Comment: @AdrianMole No it was still 40 bytes