How does nested vectors look like in memory?
So I'm considering making an global nested std::vector (vector <vector <data>> V) initially empty and later during the program, adding data to this nested vector. I'm concerned of adding too much element during run time and exceeding the stack and causing stack overflow.
So after doing some research, my understanding is that the outer vector instance V is an object on the stack that but it's contents such as the inner vector and the elements inside the inner vectors are stored in the heap.
So does that mean I don't have to worry about adding too much elements to the nested vector during runtime since the elements will be stored in the heap and not the stack?
I have a picture of how I think the nested vector V will look in memory below. Please tell me if my current understanding is correct. Thanks
My prediction of nested Vector memory layout:

Trying to understand nested vector memory layout and if adding too much elements will cause stack overflow.

Your understanding is correct - you don't need to worry about stack space when you use std::vector, since the memory for the elements is allocated on the heap. Having a nested vector does not change this. Only the lightweight "header" of the outer vector might be on the stack (if it e.g. a local variable).

... and from what I can see, your prediction looks correct in the implementations I've looked at.

Additional reading:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230802-00/?p=108524

Side note: heap and stack are implementation details and the C++ Standard describes the required behaviour in terms of Dynamic and Automatic storage. You'll probably never see it happen in the wild, but so long as the requirements laid out for Dynamic and Automatic Storage are met, anything can be used. And that includes Standing Stones, powdered unicorn horn, pixie dust, and Care Bear stuffing soaked in the blood of ritually murdered Smurfs. Damn. That got dark all of a sudden.

Good reading on why the terms Dynamic and Automatic storage are used.

not quite the same but basically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478523/how-does-stdvector-support-contiguous-memory-for-custom-objects-of-unknown-siz/55478808#55478808

Side note: Doug provides a very simple example of how to avoid a nested vector without having to change the syntax. Why would you do this? All those different blocks of memory can really suck the performance out of a program as the processor has to chase down all those pointers and almost certainly separately load the data referenced by the pointers. It's generally better to keep all of the data in one compact block.

sizeof(V) will tell you how many bytes V occupies on the stack.

std::vector does not use the stack for anything; everything in a vector is in the heap.
Of course, just in case: if you put the vector on the stack, as in
void foo()
{
   std::vector<...> something;
}

then the actual content will be in the heap as I just said, but there will be a tiny bit of management data that makes up the actual "vector" instance on the stack -- like "pointer to memory block, size of memory block, and number of elements currently used".
If you do this with a nested vector, as in
void foo()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<...>> something;
}

Then the "outer vector management data" will be on the stack, while the inner vector management data, which is the content-items of the outer vector, are all in the heap.
if you want to, try something like this:
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> test;
   std::cout << sizeof(test) << '\n';
   for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) test.push_back(i);
   std::cout << sizeof(test) << '\n';
}

You should be getting a fairly small number as the size of the vector object, and no matter how much you push into it, that won't change. And yes, any C++ "expert" will know that the sizeof() of an object can't change, but a newbie might want to see it not changing :-)

Thank you confirming. Is this also true for other dynamically sized containers like queues,stack, deques, priority queues ,etc. Where the contents of the elements are in the heap and not the stack?

It is not actually mandated in the standard, but in practice std::vector implementations are always allocating memory for the elements on the heap.
Therefore your understanding is correct, and you do not have to worry about a stack overflow when you use std::vector.
The std::vector object itself is very lightweight and contains only a few "header" like members (one of them pointing to the actual data on the heap, others can be size, capacity etc. - it depends on the implementation).
In case of a nested vector, only the "header" for the outer one might be on the stack (if you e.g. use it as a local variable).

The other answers here are good and provide correct information. But for the purposes of a visual answer, here’s a pretty pic:

This is the general case with C++ container objects. The object itself you create on the stack (as a local variable), but it’s data is allocated and stored on the heap. In the case of nested objects, such as a nested vector, again everything but the outermost object is heap-allocated.
In fact, C++ container objects have an Allocator class as part of their template which purpose is specifically the management of the object’s data (which is, by default, on the heap).
A std::vector guarantees contiguous layout of its data. But you see it does not aggregate things like a multi-dimensional array would. The contained objects are vectors, which are indeed stored as contiguous data, but as you can see each vector object maintains its own separate data store on the heap.
