# C++ - Pointer stability of returning an element from std::vector<T*>?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, std

[What does std::vector look like in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330010/what-does-stdvector-look-like-in-memory)

So I was reading the above just now and I noticed the following quote:

> Iterator and address stability of elements is guaranteed with `std::vector` **only if** no reallocation takes place

So let's say I have an `std::vector<>` member of generic type `T*` (`T` representing anything). The member itself is a pointer to the first element in the `std::vector<>` since the heap-allocated buffer is contiguous in memory and an iterator just shifts along by `sizeof(T)` bytes for each element's pointer in the `std::vector<>`.

In an `std::vector<>` of generic type `T*`, each element's pointer is just a pointer to a pointer, to my understanding at least. **Be that as it may, this means that the above address stability only applies to the element pointer and not the pointer at the element too, right?**

Comment: correct - its what's directly contained in the vector. the underlying thing that `T*` is pointing at doesn't have to move

Comment: A pointer holds a value, nothing more. The values stored in the vector don't change unless you change them.

Comment: If you had a vector full of integers, would you expect those integers to change if the underlying memory was changed?  No.  Same with pointers.

Comment: Almost all text could be replaced with a sample code. **In an `std::vector<>` of generic type `T*`** could be just `std::vector<T*>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The items pointed at by the vector do not have to change and therefore your other resources are safe to rely on the values. The memory location of the pointers of the vector will change though, because that's what reallocation does.