# What is wrong in this if I provide input to a vector like this?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

```
vector<int> a;
    
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        a[i]=i;
    }
```

I am a beginner and have just come across vectors in C++. I learned that we don't have to specify the size of vectors unlike the array beforehand. So, why can't I do this?

Answer (score 2):

> I learned that we don't have to specify the size of vectors unlike the array beforehand. So, why can't I do this?

#### Solution

Initialize the vector's size to be `n`. Then you can use `cin` like below -

```
int n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> a(n);//Vector declared with size
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];
```

The reason behind this is - vectors grow in size dynamically, if you initialize their size in compile-time itself, you can definitely `cin` the values. But if you don't initialize the size at compile-time then for vector to understand how much space to allocate you should use `push_back`.

When you don't initialize the size `n` at compile-time using `vector<int> a;` there are no values at that location so you cannot use the `[]` operator as **`[]` are for access not for resizing**. And when you initialize it as `vector<int> a(n);` the values are predominantly initialized with value `0` and since it is initialized you can use `[]` operator.

---

**Further Reading -**

[How Vectors Grow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232198/about-vectors-growth)

Comment: You may want to reword **not for writes**. You certainly can use `[]` for writing. You just cannot resize with `[]`.

Comment: In addition to the concern raised by user4581301,  the wording "pre-define" and "declaring"  a vector with a size is incorrect.   The correct description is that `vector<int> a(n)`  *initialises* the vector's size to be `n`.   Declaring means something else entirely in C++, and a definition is a type of declaration.   The fact that `vector<int> a(n)` defines (and declares) `a` doesn't mean that the size is declared or defined to be `n`.

Comment: Thank you Peter & @user4581301 ,I have made the edits & I will be more careful while writing answers. Thanks a lot for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't have to specify a vector size in some circumstances.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    a.push_back(i);
}
```

This increases the vector size, since you don't access vector's elements directory but ask to add new elements to the tail, and the vector class does job the best for you.