How much memory could std::vector consume when expanding?
In most compilers of Linux, std::vector will expand with the factor of 2. I have tested that on g++11.
So, I presume that the following will happen when std::vector expands from N to 2N:

The vector reaches its limit at N. It consumes X bytes of memory.
The vector will allocate 2*X bytes memory for an array of 2*N elements. So the vector could take 3*X bytes in total.
The vector copies or moves elements from the original N-sized array into 2*N-sized array.
The vector destructs the original array. So it now takes 2*X bytes of memory.

As a conclusion, the vector's peak memory usage should be 3*X. So, I write the following codes to test this behavior.
In the code, we will emplace 2M instances of Writes into a vector. And will use getPeakRSS to record the maximum memory take in this program.
I will print Current memory usage from time to time. The usage info is from getPeakRSS. The expected is computed by multiply the size of Writes and the current  count of vector ww. The amp field is usage / expected. If I am correct, I could find that amp has a maximum value of about 3.
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Writes16 {
    uint64_t w1;
    uint64_t w2;
};

struct Writes32 {
    Writes16 w1;
    Writes16 w2;
};

struct Writes128 {
    Writes32 w1;
    Writes32 w2;
    Writes32 w3;
    Writes32 w4;
};

struct Writes {
    Writes128 w1;
    Writes16 w2;
    uint64_t w3;
};

/*
 * Author:  David Robert Nadeau
 * Site:    http://NadeauSoftware.com/
 * License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License
 *          http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/deed.en_US
 */

#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

#elif defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix) || defined(unix) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
#include <mach/mach.h>

#elif (defined(_AIX) || defined(__TOS__AIX__)) || (defined(__sun__) || defined(__sun) || defined(sun) && (defined(__SVR4) || defined(__svr4__)))
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <procfs.h>

#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__linux) || defined(linux) || defined(__gnu_linux__)
#include <stdio.h>

#endif

#else
#error "Cannot define getPeakRSS( ) or getCurrentRSS( ) for an unknown OS."
#endif

/**
 * Returns the peak (maximum so far) resident set size (physical
 * memory use) measured in bytes, or zero if the value cannot be
 * determined on this OS.
 */
size_t getPeakRSS( )
{
#if defined(_WIN32)
    /* Windows -------------------------------------------------- */
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS info;
    GetProcessMemoryInfo( GetCurrentProcess( ), &info, sizeof(info) );
    return (size_t)info.PeakWorkingSetSize;

#elif (defined(_AIX) || defined(__TOS__AIX__)) || (defined(__sun__) || defined(__sun) || defined(sun) && (defined(__SVR4) || defined(__svr4__)))
    /* AIX and Solaris ------------------------------------------ */
    struct psinfo psinfo;
    int fd = -1;
    if ( (fd = open( "/proc/self/psinfo", O_RDONLY )) == -1 )
        return (size_t)0L;      /* Can't open? */
    if ( read( fd, &psinfo, sizeof(psinfo) ) != sizeof(psinfo) )
    {
        close( fd );
        return (size_t)0L;      /* Can't read? */
    }
    close( fd );
    return (size_t)(psinfo.pr_rssize * 1024L);

#elif defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix) || defined(unix) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))
    /* BSD, Linux, and OSX -------------------------------------- */
    struct rusage rusage;
    getrusage( RUSAGE_SELF, &rusage );
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    return (size_t)rusage.ru_maxrss;
#else
    return (size_t)(rusage.ru_maxrss * 1024L);
#endif

#else
    /* Unknown OS ----------------------------------------------- */
    return (size_t)0L;          /* Unsupported. */
#endif
}

std::vector<Writes> ww;

int main() {
    static_assert(sizeof(Writes) == 152);
    const size_t K = 1024;
    const size_t M = 1024 * K;
    size_t location = 0;
    for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            ww.emplace_back(Writes());
            if (j % 4096 == 0) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    location = (size_t)&ww[0];
                }
                size_t usage = getPeakRSS();
                size_t expected = ww.size() * 152;
                double rate = usage * 1.0 / expected;
                printf("Current memory usage %d: %u %.4fMB expected %u %.4fMB amp %.4f cap %u\n", m, usage, usage / 1024.0 / 1024.0, expected, expected / 1024.0 / 1024.0, rate, ww.capacity());
            }
        }
    }
    // To ensure the elements are copied. There is no realloc happening.
    printf("Location prev %u end %u\n", location, (size_t)&ww[0]);
    return 0;
}

However, I found the following. Seems that during expanding, the peak memory usages is only 2*X bytes, rather than 3*X.
...
Current memory usage 0: 163250176 155.6875MB expeted 158761112 151.4064MB amp 1.0283 cap 1048576
Current memory usage 1: 322584576 307.6406MB expeted 159383704 152.0001MB amp 2.0239 cap 2097152
...

I wonder why the extra X bytes is saved?
=====
I understand that how std::vector expands is totally compiler dependent. So I want to know what optimization could happen in g++, that makes some memory allocations "eliminated".

First, capacity growth depends on compiler. Second, memory allocation also depends on implementation, usually there are several pools of memory and allocators don't return memory until necessary to improve performance.

Vector often grows at 1.5x each step instead of 2x.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232198/how-does-the-capacity-of-stdvector-grow-automatically-what-is-the-rate

There is an identifier, size_t, which is the maximum value that a container can take.  See what the value is for your machine.  Theoretically, the std::vector can take up all the memory that your system is capable of (maybe more depending of virtual memory).

@NathanOliver I understand your point. However, as Gene pointed out, this mechanism is totally compiler-dependant. In my environment(which is g++11), it is tested to grow at factor of 2. I just wonder what could happen so that the extra memory allocation is not happen.

The vector is reserving memory space. That doesn't mean that all its space is actually stored in RAM. That might only happen if the space is used for storing data.

@BoP -- yes, usually OS doesn't commit memory until it's used.

@BoP But vector must have contiguous memory. Do you mean these memories are reserved, but not actually allocated by the system. When the newly allocated memory is required, some page-fault could happen, then the memory is allocated, and is observable by getPeakRSS?

Yes, that's the way virtual memory work in general.

@calvin -- you are mixing virtual and physical memory, the application can only deal with virtual memory

@calvin - Yes, the vector requires contiguous virtual memory, which doesn't all have to be resident at all times. Specifically, unused parts might not have gotten any RAM allocated.

Since this is all internal to the implementation, it can use shortcuts. For instance, it might use C malloc() and realloc(). And realloc() can avoid making a copy if there's available contiguous space to grow in place.

@Barmar it cannot use realloc. std::vector has to stick to the std::allocator interface and that does not support realloc-like operations.

You may be interested in the presentation *(char*)0 = 0; by JF Bastien.

The difference is between residual and virtual memory.
Let's simplify what's going on by going from one large allocation, let's say 1M, to the next higher allocation, 2M:

The vector allocates a size. Through the new-allocator it ultimately resolves into a new memory mapping. This allocates virtual memory space but it is not yet populated with physical memory, so it doesn't consume RSS. In various utilities this virtual memory shows up as AS (meaning address space e.g. in prlimit) or as VIRT (e.g. in top)
The vector slowly fills this memory from the front. As each new memory page is written to for the first time, a page-fault occurs at which point the operating system allocates a new physical memory page. This slowly grows the RSS. Of course the OS may optimize this and allocate more than one page at once, but it will not allocate all at once
Vector runs out of capacity. It allocates new memory, twice the original size. As in step 1, this memory is newly allocated virtual memory with no physical memory attached, therefore the RSS does not grow
The vector now copies the existing elements to the new mapping. As in step 2, this grows the RSS but only as much as the first mapping's size
The old mapping is now deallocated. Since it is a huge allocation, the new-allocator will release it back to the operating system. This shrinks the RSS back to about 50%
The vector now continues to grow into the remaining mapped memory

The peak RSS use occurs at the end of step 4. At this point, the old mapping of 1M elements is fully mapped. However, the new mapping is only filled by half, the existing 1M elements. The extra capacity that was allocated has not yet been touched, therefore was not allocated a physical memory page and therefore does not account for RSS. This is the amp factor of 2 that you observe.
If you looked at virtual memory / address space of the process, you would see the expected factor of 3.
