# Why std::make_move_iterator works on vector<string> but not on vector<int>

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, move-semantics

I was expecting that `std::make_move_iterator` will always *move* contents, but it seems not.

It looks like it is moving elements in `vector<string>` but not in `vector<int>`.

See the below code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void moveIntVector()
{
  std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
  std::vector<int> v1;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    v1.push_back(i);
  }
  std::vector<int> v2(
    std::make_move_iterator(v1.begin() + 5),
    std::make_move_iterator(v1.end()));
  std::cout << "v1 is: ";
  for (auto i : v1) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << "v2 is: ";
  for (auto i : v2) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void moveStringVector()
{
  std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
  std::vector<std::string> v1;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    v1.push_back(std::to_string(i));
  }
  std::vector<std::string> v2(
    std::make_move_iterator(v1.begin() + 5),
    std::make_move_iterator(v1.end()));
  std::cout << "v1 is: ";
  for (auto i : v1) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << "v2 is: ";
  for (auto i : v2) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  moveIntVector();
  moveStringVector();
  return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
moveIntVector
v1 is: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  # I expect this should be `0 1 2 3 4` as well!
v2 is: 5 6 7 8 9 
moveStringVector
v1 is: 0 1 2 3 4      
v2 is: 5 6 7 8 9
```

I'm on `Ubuntu 14.04, gcc 4.8.2` and the code is compiled with `-std=c++11`

Could you explain why `std::make_move_iterator` have different behaviour on `vector<int>` and `vector<string>`? (Or is it a bug?)

Comment: Note that in your `moveStringVector`'s output for `v1`, there are extra spaces at the end from the empty strings left over from the move.

Comment: Err... did you seriously create two functions `move*Vector()` which handle a **template** class for two types in exactly identical fashion and are 99% identical to the letter? Whose name even indicates that the type is the only difference? It's bothering me so much that I feel this *urge* to go right now and consolidate that into a template function ;-). I mean, even the output operator is a template (as opposed to `printf`). The only difference would be in the initialization which could be passed in as an array. Or, actually, initialize the vector with an initializer list.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The behaviour is expected. A move from both vectors leaves the original `v1` with 5 moved-from elements in their second half.

The difference is that when the strings are moved, what is left behind is empty strings. This is because it is a very efficient way to move strings, and leave the moved-from string in a self-consistent state (Technically, they could be left to hold the value `"Hello, World, nice move!"`, but that would incur extra cost). The bottom line is that you don't see those moved-from strings in your output.

In the case of the `int` vectors, there is no way to move an `int` that is more efficient than copying it, so they are just copied over.

If you check the sizes of the vectors, you will see the `v1` have size 10 in both cases.

Here's a simplified example to illustrate that the moved from strings are left empty:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v1{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
    std::vector<std::string> v2(std::make_move_iterator(v1.begin()),
                                std::make_move_iterator(v1.end()));

    std::cout << "v1 size " << v1.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "v1: ";
    for (const auto& s : v1) std::cout << s << " - ";
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "v2 size " << v2.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "v2: ";
    for (const auto& s : v2) std::cout << s << " - ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
v1 size 5
v1:  -  -  -  -  - 
v2 size 5
v2: a - b - c - d - e -
```

Comment: +1, but I'd put it differently: there are efficient ways to move an `int`, and the most efficient way is to copy it. (I define "move" from `a` to `b` as making sure `b` gets the value of `a`, and `a` remains in a valid state. Copying is always one way of moving, even for `string`, it just so happens that it's not a particularly good way for `string`.)

Comment: @hvd I agree. I re-phrased that part of the answer.

Comment: Is there any way to *really* move (or split) the vector into two parts? e.g. in my case, I would like to get v1 with first 5 elements and v2 with last 5 elements, while not copying them but actually moving (splitting) them.

Comment: @Mine The simplest way that springs to mind is to erase the unwanted elements after moving them: `v0.erase(v0 + 5, v0.end());`

Comment: OK. Got it though it is not what I want. Anyway, that explains why it's better to operate with iterators rather than the containers.

Comment: @Mine You can `move` the entire vector, typically leaving an empty vector behind. Interesting idea to move something like a slice into another container. For a vector that would only be efficient for end slices, but for other containers it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 7):

When we talk about a **move** we are not talking about moving the object itself (it remains intact). What gets moved are its internal data. This may or may not affect the value of the object whose internal data gets moved.

That is why your `int` array doesn't loose its original `int`s. As to your string example, it still has the original `std::strings` just like the `int` example but their internal values have changed to empty strings.

It is important to remember that internally a `std::string` (essentially) holds a pointer to a character array. So when you **copy** a `std::string` you copy every element of the character array. A **move**, however, avoids doing all that copying by copying the internal pointer instead.

But if the **move** operation stopped there that would leave both `std::string`s pointing at the same character array and changing the character data pointed to by either `std::string` would also change the other's. So when you **move** a string it is not enough to merely **copy** the internal pointer, you have to make the internal pointer of the `std::string` you moved from point to a new blank character array so that it can no longer affect the string its data was moved to.

When moving an `int` there is no further action required after the copy of its data. There are no pointers involved so after the copy both ints contain independent data.

Answer (score 0):

**move constructor** is like of an object works like taking a regular reference and a instruction to move things. the **default move constructor** tries to call the move constructor of all member variables. a user defined one... pretty much it's up to the programmer to tell it what to do.
you could program your objects to be in a undefined state after being subject to a move constructor, you can keep them unchanged(the destructor will still be called so you need to take care of that), you can keep them valid. strings will have a defined state after being subject to a move constructor.

as for your example...

**int** is trivially copyable and it's **move constructor** won't do anything but copying.

**string** is not trivially copyable. it has some dynamic stuff in it that the move constructor moves. and the previous one is left with a length of zero, you ARE printing them, along with the trailing "space" which you added. it's just they are the last 5 elements, at the end of what your printing and you aren't noticing it because it's equivalent to 5 trailing white spaces.