# Iteratively insert into std::list and then convert to std::vector for random access?

Tags: c++, list, vector

Say I have a situation where I'm populating a vector/list iteratively, and I don't know how many elements there will be beforehand. For example, the code might look more or less like this:

```
std::vector<MyClass> mythings;
for(int i = 0; i < *some number*; ++i){
    if(*some condition here*){
        mythings.push_back(MyClass());
    }
}
```

I know that `push_back` isn't very efficient when used for `std::vector`. So in the above chunk of code I could change `mythings` to a `std::list`, and presumably that would be faster, since `std::list` is implemented as a linked list. However, say that I know that I'll need to do random access on the list/vector I just created. For random access, `std::vector` would be much faster. So using `std::vector` and `std::list` both have their disadvantages in this scenario.

In this situation, would it be more efficient for me to use a `std::list` when creating the list/vector, and then convert it to a `std::vector` afterwards (for example, as in this question: [One liner to convert from list<T> to vector<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218713/one-liner-to-convert-from-listt-to-vectort)) so that I can take advantage of the random access of `std::vector`? Or would the cost of the conversion outweigh the gain?

Comment: If `*some number*` is known, using `std::vector` with pre-allocation via `reserve()` may be better.

Comment: How about doing some experiments?

Comment: Why isn't `push_back` efficient? Is this code really your program's bottleneck after profiling? If not, you may be prematurely trying to optimize it. Approximately how many elements are we talking about with `* some number *` here?

Comment: @ggorlen in my situation `*some number*` could be as big or bigger than 1,000,000, and the condition likely won't be true very often - which is why I'm hesitant to pre-allocate as suggested by MikeCAT

Comment: @dfriend21 So, you **do** know `*some number*` beforehand?

Comment: It depends. Possible things to try are preallocating the vector, using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` and/or using `std::move` to add to `mythings`, use `std::deque`, or iterating thru once to count the number of things that will be added, preallocating, then iterating thru to add them.

Comment: @dfriend21 I assume `push_back` forces a non-preallocated vector to make at most log(n) reallocation calls. Is 20 reallocations really destroying your app's performance that badly? Recommended reading: [Eric Lippert: performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @eerorika yes, but I don't know how often the condition will be `true`

Comment: @ggorlen Honestly in my situation I don't think it'll make a huge difference either way (although I'd need to run tests to be sure). It was just something that occurred to me, and it seemed like an interesting concept. Also, I'm no C++ expert so I wasn't sure if it was a stupid idea or not, so I thought I'd run it past people who know more than I do - it sounds like the answer is "it depends" - so at least I know it wasn't a totally absurd idea :)

Comment: Re: "presumably [`std::list`] would be faster" for insertions -- not necessarily. Be careful about making assumptions based on simplifications. `std::list` does a fair amount of work for **every** insertion, while `std::vector` does a lot of work **once in a while**. If speed of insertions is the most important factor in your application, measure the times involved. If speed of insertions is not a limiting factor for performance, just use `std::vector` so you can get random access.

Answer (score 1):

> In this situation, would it be more efficient for me to use a std::list

Probably not. This would typically be more expensive than pushing to the vector directly.

> Or would the cost of the conversion outweigh the gain?

The high cost of the list in general is mostly the problem.

---

To find out whether these reasonable assumptions are actually true, you should measure them. If you measure one to be significantly faster, then that may be the more efficient choice.

Bonus hint: Don't push_back, but emplace_back. That can be a bit faster depending on the class.

Here are alternatives that I recommend measuring:

- Just a simple vector and emplace.
- Reserve vector with `*some number*`, `shrink_to_fit` after filling the vector.
- Maybe try deque instead.